# Don't allow sites to set custom protocol handlers?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, protocol-handler

Some annoying person decided it would be funny to make a site which sets custom protocol handlers (irc:, bitcoin:, etc.) on chrome to go to their site.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This copied from [online help](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/chrome/configure-chrome-with-service-handlers/):

Service handlers often provide helpful features to deal with specific protocols and in Chrome they are enabled by default. You can disable or re-enable them via the Chrome settings menu:

- Select the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar
- Select Settings
- Select Show advanced settings
- In the Privacy section select Content settings
- Locate the “Handlers” section:

  - To enable: select Allow sites to ask to become default handlers for protocols
  - To disable: select Do not allow any site to handle protocols

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you.